# <textarea> has some text, after updating it in form, change is not reflecting while submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I wanted to construct a **form**, When it loads, it should have data which is currently stored in back end DB. At the same time user should be able to change content and submit **form** to update DB.

For this purpose I have used **input** and **textarea** elements. **textarea** is used to show email. But after update data, data of input elements changed but not for **textarea**

**Here is code:**

*In HTML Form this is **textarea**, Where text is echoed via PHP*

```
<textarea placeholder="EMAIL" class="form-control" rows="2" cols="6" id="email" style="resize:none;"><?php echo $retention_config['email'] ?></textarea>
```

In browser I updated the email content of this

After that before submitting data, I wished to validate that this field should not be empty, for this used JS

*Here is JS code:*

```
var email_text = $('#email').text().trim();

if(email_text == "") {
  alert("Email is Mandatory");
}
```

But, I was not getting this alert, after deleting whole content of email, Then I checked the value of this  using javascript.

```
console.log('#email').text();
```

I got the text which, i initially loaded via PHP, When I updated text in form it should be updated then, Please help, as I ran into this problem for first time. Please forgive me if there is any error in this post as I am learning to post in stack overflow, earlier only I got ready made help from this platform only.

Comment: Please show code how you are updating the `text` of `textarea`

Comment: `var email_text = $('#email').text().trim();` must be changed to `var email_text = $('#email').val().trim();` to get the required answer.

Comment: Add `required` attribute to the textarea instead...

Comment: Why do you use textarea instead of `<input type="email">`?

Comment: @Leopard Text is being updated in browser

Comment: @Endless Email doesn't contains email_id.  It contains email content for which input box is not sufficient.

Comment: @Mani7TAM Thanks, it is working, why I not tried that, I thought textarea do not respond to value attribute, as we cannot set text in textarea by value attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `input` so you need to get the `value` of it, as you are using jQuery you can use `val()`, like so:

```
var email_text = $('#email').val().trim();
if(email_text == "") {
    alert("Email is Mandatory");
}
```

and your console  log would be:

```
console.log($('#email').val());
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, why i not tried that thing, is because you cannot set text in textarea with value attribute. But it is working fine in this condition. i.e. while fetching content in JS

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `val` instead of `text`

```
var email_text = $('#email').val().trim();

if(email_text == "") {
  alert("Email is Mandatory")
}
```